# Windows Store Apps: change application culture at runtime without restarting the application?

Tags: windows-8, localization, windows-runtime

I have a windows store app that supports English (LTR) and Arabic (RTL).

I want to add an option in the settings to enable the user to change the app culture from English to Arabic and vice versa.

I want the string resources and the UI flow direction to change immediately without having to restart the application.

how can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for changing the culture (not sure abot the LTR/RTL). Let me know, if it works. Maybe you would need to refresh localization bindings after setting the new culture.

```cs
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
```

Comment: It changes the culture only, the current page flow direction does not change immediately, only newly navigated pages are affected. is there a way to make sure that layout changes take place immediately ?

Comment: It seems that you need to restart the app before culture changes take place, there is now way to reflect the changes in runtime.

Comment: You just have to either reset the DataContext or the localization bindings. It works even without restarting the app.

Comment: can you explain more how to change the localizations bindings ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
```

Only works if put AFTER the "Frame rootFrame" creation in App OnLaunched event. I use to develop using one language at design time and another at runtime, what makes easy to check the use of resources.